# How is this proposition false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a proposition:

`((x v y) <=> (~x => ~y))`

When I solve this, I end up getting `True` but the answer is `False`. Here's how I solved it:

when we have `a <=> b`, we can write it as `~a.~b + a.b` and `a => b` becomes `~a+b`
So the above equation becomes:

=> `~(x + y).~(~x => ~y) + (x + y).(~x => ~y)`

=> `~(x+y).~(x+~y) + (x+y).(x+~y)`

Using De Morgan's law (`~(a+b) = ~a.~b` and `~(a.b) = ~a+~b`)

=> `(~x.~y).(~x.y) + (x+y).(x+~y)`

=> `(~x.~x + ~x.y + ~y.~x + ~y.y) + (x.x + x.~y + y.x + y.~y)`

=> `(~x + ~x(y+~y) + 0) + (x + x(~y + y) + 0)`

=> `(~x + ~x) + (x + x)`

=> `~x + x` which is always `True`

But, according to another solution, `<=>` is only `True` when both sides result in the same solution, So, if we go by this:

=> LHS = `x+y` and RHS is `(x + ~y)`, which can never be equal and hence, `False`.

So what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

PS: [This](https://youtu.be/eA0ENyDowzo?t=3138) is where I got the question from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After line "Using De Morgan's law"
You should have  $$(\neg x.\neg y).(\neg x.y) + (x+y).(x+\neg y)$$
$$0+x+x .\neg y+y.x +y.\neg y$$
$$x+x.(y+\neg y) = x$$
So you end up with $x$: initial equivalence is True **together** with $x$

Comment: How did you go from the first line to the next?

Comment: In first member you have $\neg y.y=0$, in second member open brackets.

Comment: So something like what @mathcounterexamples.net is trying to say? There's no distributive law between • and •. Only between • and +

Comment: Yes. Distributive property we have between "$\cdot$" and "$+$" and reverse - also between "$+$" and "$\cdot$".

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one mistake when you go from:

$$\neg (x+y).\neg (x+ \neg y) + (x+y).(x+ \neg y)$$ to

$$(\neg x. \neg y).(\neg x.y) + (x.y).(x+ \neg y)$$ using De Morgan laws. You switched $x+y$ into $x . y$.

Also I don't understand how you go from this line to the next one:

$$(\neg x.\neg x + \neg x.y + \neg y.\neg x + \neg y.y) + (x.x + x.\neg y + y.x + y.\neg y).$$

It seems that you apply a kind of distributivity of $.$ over itself???

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. The first one was a mistake, which I have edited. Sorry about that.

I did apply the distributive property. But that's valid, right?

Comment: No, you don't have such a distributivity law of $\cdot$ vs. $\cdot$. One exists for $\cdot$ vs. $+$.

Answer (score 1):

> When I solve this, I end up getting True but the answer is False

The answer is not `False`. You can check it yourself by setting `x=True`, `y=True`, in which case you get

```
(T+T)<=>(F=>F)
```

which simplifies to

```
T <=> T
```

and further to just `T`.

The answer is also not `True`, and you can check this by setting `x=False`, `y=True` and you get

```
(T+T)<=>(T=>F)
```

which simplifies to

```
T <=> F
```

and further to just `F`.

---

> => LHS = `x+y` and RHS is `(x + ~y)`, which can never be equal and hence, `False`.

This is incorrect. So long as `x` is true, `x+y` and `x+~y` can be equal (i.e., both true.

Comment: So if I get this option to a question like "which one is False?", should I tick this option?

Comment: @SarvagyaGupta No. The statement is not False. The statement depends on the truth value of the input $x$.